# the difference between ル and タ when the verb shows status

Tags: grammar, verbs, tense, attributive

I am wondering how ル (original form of a verb) and タ work when it comes to a status verb. For example:

> 絵を目立つ場所にかける

I think 絵を目立った場所にかける is natural, because I often see 青目をしたお人形, 優れた人になりたい, 際立った特徴 and so on.

From what I know, for the verb like 切る and 出会う, which can be done in one-second (瞬間動詞？) the difference between ル-form and タ-form is clearer than the verb which emphasizes status... (that's more similar to the difference between 完了 and 未然), the problem is, for the status verb, how I can know when should I use タ when to use ル？

Where can I get more 文献 relating to the topic? What keywords should I search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 絵を目立つ場所にかける (the original text)
>
> However, from my point of view 絵を目立った場所にかける is natural... Because in Japanese, I often see 青目をしたお人形, 優れた人になりたい, 際立った特徴 and so on.
>
> 切る and 出会う (瞬間動詞)、 the difference between ル-form and タ-form is clearer
>   (that's more similar to the difference between 完了 and 未然)
>
> for the status verb, how I can know when should I use タ when to use ル？

I like the way you put them; た is about completion (完了), and る is the basic verb form (未然).

I feel that 目立つ場所 in 絵を目立つ場所にかける is saying somewhere the picture **will** stand out if it's hung there.
If it's 絵を目立った場所にかける, it says (someone) hangs pictures somewhere prominent.